# Right way to implement authentication for api-based service

Tags: django, authentication, web, django-rest-framework, mobile-application

I'm working on a service with REST-api implemented on django rest framework. I'l have web-site with frontend on javascript (possibly, SPA on  Knockout), android and iOS apps, which all will be using this API. What is the best way to handle authentication in this case?

I'v read a lot on JWT-tokens (not my case, i must have ability to revoke auth for particular user at any time), sessions (already using django), storing tokens in localStorage and so on.

Should I have one type (tokens?) for all? Or is it normal, to use cookie-based session auth for web and tokens for mobile apps? If web also goes with tokens, where is the best way to store them: cookies or localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use many authentication methods.

For web app this can be session base auth, assuming that you run it on the same domain. For mobile app you use tokens. DRF will check all methods defined [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme).

Therefore, remember to enable/disable correct ones.